# Symfony 2.0 datetime widget; how to render with JQuery UI date picker?

Tags: jquery-ui, symfony

I have a Symfony 2.0 app.

It has a datetime field on an entity, and a datetime field on a form.

How can I have the date part of that form render with a jQuery UI date picker instead of the 3 select boxes?

Thanks,

EDIT

This is what I have so far:

```
$builder->add('start_at', 'datetime',array('date_widget' => 'single_text'));
```

This puts a text box on the page for the date then 2 select boxes for the time, and you can easily add a jQuery UI on top of that!

The problem is the Symfony datetime field only accepts input in the format "Aug 29, 2012". If the user types in "Aug 29 2012" or "29 Aug 2012" it refuses to validate.

So anyone who can fix that problem or suggest an entirely different working approach would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you also have a typo where 'date_widget' => should be just 'widget' => at least that's how I do my jQuery datepickers from datefields.

Comment: @mattias Note I'm using a datetime not a date field. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up using this code

```
    $builder->add('start_at', 'datetime' ,array(
            'date_widget'=> 'single_text',
            'date_format'=>'d/M/y',
            ....
        ));
```

then putting jQuery UI on top of it, and just dealing with the fact that it only accepts input in one format only.

Comment: James i have the same issue. I defined it like you, but always I get 'This value is not valid' in the controller. even 'M d, yy' is not valid. what is the correct format for symfony?

Comment: @Aris the correct format for symfony should be yyyy-MM-dd

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this bundle. It provides several extra form types, including a jquery date form field:

https://github.com/genemu/GenemuFormBundle

Comment: That seems to be a date field  - is that right? I am specifically after a datetime field.

Comment: I know, but you could use jQuery UI for the date part of the field and leave the time part as the select boxes.

Comment: Well, you could look at how the GenemuFormBundle implements this and implement something similar yourself