# Symfony2 editForm datetime object in formbuilder but I need it to be a string

Tags: php, forms, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

For starters, I'm new to symfony2 -> coming from Laravel and ZF1 I have to admit it is not what I expected. I had a lot of struggle with simple tasks and by the moment of writing this twig editing is still a pain.

So scenario:

I have a invoice form with 2 datetime fields in it, I really hate that ugly 3 select field that is generated so I included my jQuery datepicker.

http://tinypic.com/r/eg5kyg/8

For my initial insertion of data because of the datetime I needed to create my form with a input type "text" :

```
$form=$this->createFormBuilder($invoice)
                        ->add('date_ref','text', array(
                            'required'=> true))
                        ->add('date_sent','text', array(
                            'required' => true ))
```

In this way that ugly 3 select datepicker is not shown and my users can select a date in an elegant way.

All good until the edit form:

I don't know why I didn't managed to get this done as i initially wished :

```
$invoice = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Invoice')->find($id);
$form=$this->createFormBuilder($invoice)
                        ->add('date_ref','text', array(
                            'required'=> true))
                        ->add('date_sent','text', array(
                            'required' => true ))
                        ->add('value','integer',array('required'=>true))
                        ->add('nr_ref','text',array('required'=>true))
```

So i wanted to create a form from a entity with his properties but in the view

```
<div class="form-group">
                        {{ form_label(theForm.date_ref, 'Date Refferenced', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'control-label col-md-5'} }) }}
                        {{ form_errors(theForm.date_ref) }}
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            {{ form_widget(theForm.date_ref,{'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'data-provide':'datepicker'}}) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Was not working so I couldn't create my Edit Form as my first form with the date_ref input with a "text" value.

I searched and found out that creating a form from a entity data you need to create a "Type" so I created my "InvoiceType"

which has :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('is_paid')
 /* not working
   ->add('date_ref', 'date', array('input'  => 'datetime',
                                            'format' => date('y-M-d'),
                                            'widget' => 'single_text'))
   */
      ->add('date_ref')    //this is a datetime obj which results in those 5 selects
     ->add('date_sent')
            ->add('value')
            ->add('nr_ref')
            ->add('name_provider')
        ;
    }

$invoice = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Invoice')->find($id);
$form = $this->createForm(new InvoiceType(), $invoice);
```

But because this method creates a form from the entity, if I change the type from the buildForm() function  .. I get an error that he expects a Object of Datetime instead of a string ("text").

So now I am stuck at making the Edit Form .. that would be a type, 1 input Text and pre-populated with the date from the Database(something like 2014/02/02) using datepicker and when you click on it, it should appear as in the create form.

Like I said I am new, I learned a lot of things that I normally done other ways in other MVC and I struggle a lot with this datetime Object and symfonys 3 select datetime.

http://tinypic.com/r/28bz5h4/8
<- This looks awful

Comment: I hope if you cover documentation properly you can use datatime field and it can be rendered as text type for now this is a start http://stackoverflow.com/a/15537698/853360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot Khalid Junaid, after I looked up the post you have mentioned I finally got it working as i wanted:

Solution:

```
->add('date_ref', 'date' ,array(
                'widget'=> 'single_text',
                'format'=>'d/M/y'))
 ->add('date_sent','date' ,array(
                'widget'=> 'single_text',
                'format'=>'d/M/y'))
```